# EF Add doesn't seem to be adding anything?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this C# method is asp.net webapi :

```
public IHttpActionResult Definitions()
        {
            var words = db.Words
                .Where(w => w.Name == "abandon")
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList();

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                HttpResponse<string> response = Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word.Name)
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxx")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .asJson<string>();
                RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Body);
                var results = rootObject.results;
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    if (!(from d in db.WordDefinitions where d.Definition == result.definition select d).Any())
                    {
                        var pos = 0;
                        switch (result.partOfSpeech)
                        {
                            case "noun":
                                pos = 1;
                                break;
                            case "verb":
                                pos = 2;
                                break;
                            case "adjective":
                                pos = 3;
                                break;
                            case "Adverb":
                                pos = 4;
                                break;
                            default:
                                pos = 5;
                                break;
                        }
                        var definition = new WordDefinition()
                        {
                            WordId = word.WordId,
                            Definition = result.definition,
                            PosId = pos
                        };
                        db.WordDefinitions.Add(definition);
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                } 
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

The code runs from start to finish. When I put a breakpoint on db.SaveChanges() I see it reaching that point multiple times and I see that definition is populated.

But when I check the database there's nothing added.

Is there a way that I can add some checks that might point me to what is going wrong? I suspected there was an exception but then I think not as the code keeps running right to the end of the method.

Comment: Are you sure this line `db.WordDefinitions.Add(definition);` is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing that db.SaveChanges after the complete lists gets added to WordDefinitions.. I mean after the scope of outer foreach.. Its better to have that line of code outside the scope because each time it will hit the db and save your data which will relatively take some more time when compared to doing like this...

Code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Definitions()
    {
        var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => w.Name == "abandon")
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            HttpResponse<string> response = Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word.Name)
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxx")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .asJson<string>();
            RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Body);
            var results = rootObject.results;
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (!(from d in db.WordDefinitions where d.Definition == result.definition select d).Any())
                {
                    var pos = 0;
                    switch (result.partOfSpeech)
                    {
                        case "noun":
                            pos = 1;
                            break;
                        case "verb":
                            pos = 2;
                            break;
                        case "adjective":
                            pos = 3;
                            break;
                        case "Adverb":
                            pos = 4;
                            break;
                        default:
                            pos = 5;
                            break;
                    }
                    var definition = new WordDefinition()
                    {
                        WordId = word.WordId,
                        Definition = result.definition,
                        PosId = pos
                    };
                    db.WordDefinitions.Add(definition);
                }

            } 
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```